# What Event is Triggered on Save Click in ckEditor?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, ckeditor, fckeditor

I've added a ckeditor editor instance to my asp.net application. Now, I want to capture when the user clicks on the save button in the ckeditor toolbar - but I haven't been able to find what event is triggered by ckeditor when the save button is triggered. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this question that I asked a while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272377/update-editor-content-immediately-before-save-in-ckeditor-plug-in) may be relevant. One of the CKEditor developers suggested the `getData` event.

Comment: Thanks. I guess even before that step...what event is being triggered by the save button? I can't perform a getData unless I know in what event/function to place this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no special CKEditor event triggered when you click the save button. There is definitely a `getData` event, not just a `getData()` method.